# I Lost My Boot Selection menu Screen

Tags: boot, grub2

I recently had a problem

I have both Ubuntu and Windows 7 on my laptop side-by-side.  When I boot up my computer I  am shown a boot screen to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

Then I formatted the partition that had Windows. But in the boot menu, Windows still appeared, but of course it's not really there, so if choose Windows, it tells me something like wrong boot record.

I have 3 partitions on my laptop:

```
50GB - Ubuntu
100GB ext4
80GB also ext4
```

Recently, I formatted the 80GB partition and changed the file system to NTFS and I
installed windows there.

But now the Boot Menu is gone, although I have Ubuntu installed!

How can I get that boot screen back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Primary Method:

You appear to have overwritten GRUB(the thing that gives you the boot menu) with the Windows MBR. You need to boot the Ubuntu installation CD, and then open file manager and open your linux root partition(the one with /boot, /var, /sys, /etc, etc)(this mounts it). Close that window, but don't click the "eject" button next to your hard disk, unless you opened the wrong one. Now, enter, in the terminal:

```
grub-install --root-directory=<grub directory> /dev/sda
```

where to get the `<grub-directory>` part, enter /media/and then use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to "auto-complete" the correct directory. If all goes well, when you reboot, you'll have a working GRUB system.

## Alternative method:

Obtain the Super Grub Disc(not Super grub disc 2), boot to it, pick `GNU/Linux`, and pick `Fix boot of GNU/Linux`. If all goes well, you'll be able to boot Ubuntu, where you'll be able to run `update-grub` from a terminal to ensure that GRUB2 is installed, and has an option for Windows.